# k2 simple image gallery display at module position

Tags: plugin, k2, positions

I want to display gallery at module position associated with k2 item. Currently it display at bottom of K2 Item but I want to display it at Module Position "Right" How is it possible?[image]

[image]

Comment: I want to display image gallery (simple image gallery pro) and related items  in module position

Comment: The only posible and elegant solution is to program a module that get the active k2 item and render the gallery. I have been locking for in JED but there is not such a thing.

Comment: The ugly but effective solution is to use CSS to made the gallery to have an absolute position and place it on the right column.