# Plugin result at module position

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, templates, k2

Can I display Plugin result in module position.
I want to display allvideo plugin in module position.
AllVideo associate video with K2 Item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new "Custom HTML" module and place it on the position you want.

In order to use the Allvideo plugin inside this new module you use this sintax:

{format/provider}filename{/format/provider}

For instance:

{youtube}he73js82|600|450|1{/youtube}

Check this:

http://www.joomlaworks.net/support/docs/allvideos

For more info about how to use it.

Comment: Also remember to enable Prepare Content setting of the module for the  Joomla plugins.

Comment: I have 200 k2 items. if I associate videos with all items then I published 200 modules? is it possible to other method?

Comment: I see you are looking the answer for this question: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13852/k2-simple-image-gallery-display-at-module-position  I have a posible solution for that but I think it is better to answer in the other question